# How to make dplyr %>% work in rserve-js and Rserve

Tags: r, rserve

```
client.eval("result<-subset(data,Sym1=="fever" | Sym1=="headache" |Sym1=='cough')", function(err, response){

    });

    client.eval("result%>%", function(err, response){ 


    });
    client.eval("group_by(Disease)%>%", function(err, response){ 


    });
       client.eval("mutate(n=n())%>%", function(err, response){ 


    });
        client.eval("filter(n==max(n))%>%", function(err, response){ 


    });
         client.eval("select(-n)", function(err, response){ 


    });
```

there is error while executing this code but works fine while coding in R only. 
Error in -n : invalid argument to unary operator
this is the error i get. please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain separate commands with callbacks, a call to eval does not block for completion.

```
c.eval('f <- function (a, b) a+b', function (error, response) {
  c.eval('f(4, 5)' function (error, response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
})
```

Alternatively look at rserve-js unit tests where he promisified the library and chained promises.

Or you can send all of your code in a single eval